# Conditional formatting Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want A1 on Sheet1 to change color based on specific text in cell B1 on Sheet2 or even different Book...is that even possible with custum formula?

Tnx in advance

P.S. =ISText(indirect("Sheet2!B1")) this is working but dosent matters what text
i put in and i want it to be specific word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Regexmatch` instead of `Istext` :

```
=REGEXMATCH(indirect("Sheet2!B1"),"specific string to check")
```

The second argument of regexmatch is a regular expression so you can use operator like `|`,`.`,`/` or escape them with `\`. Also be sure to pay attention at lower/upper case issues because it's case-sensitive.